# how to add next and previous button along with some page number in pagination using javaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js

Hi have done some basic pagination and it is working fine now i need to add next and previous button.Please help me it would great appreciation.
PFB screenshot what i have developed.
[image]
After clicking page number 5, page number 6 and 7 appear.
[image]
Now I just want to add previous and next button.
PFB my code.

```
displayDetailsPage(success, index) {
    console.log(this);
    const mbmleaseArrList = JSON.parse(success);
    console.log(mbmleaseArrList.length);
    let htmlpagedisplay = '';
    let i;
    let htmlBuild = '';
    const start = Math.max(0, index - 2);
    const end = Math.min(start + 5, mbmleaseArrList.length - 1);
           if ((i + 1) !== 1) {
        htmlpagedisplay += (`<button value="${1}" id='pageshow' class="mb-lease-report__lilist" data-pageNo-show=${0}>First</button>`);
    }
    for (i = start; i < end; i += 1) {
        htmlpagedisplay += (`<button value="${i + 1}" id='pageshow' class="mb-lease-report__lilist" data-pageNo-show=${i}>${i + 1}</button>`);
    }
    if ((i + 1) !== mbmleaseArrList.length - 1) {
        htmlpagedisplay += (`<button value="${mbmleaseArrList.length - 1}" id='pageshow' class="mb-lease-report__lilist" data-pageNo-show=${mbmleaseArrList.length - 1}>Last</button>`);
    }
    resultDisplay.innerHTML = htmlBuild;
    resultDisplay1.innerHTML = htmlpagedisplay;}

    document.addEventListener(EVENTS.CLICK, (e) => {//here i have written the event listener when I was clicking on the page it gets triggered. 
        console.log(this);
        if (e.target && e.target.matches(`#${ID.PAGESHOW}`)) {
            e.preventDefault();
            const inputs = document.getElementById(`${ID.SHOW}`).value;
            const index = e.target.getAttribute('data-pageNo-show');
            const url = '/bin/microsites/mb-lease-report-pagination';
            const data = {
                formData: inputs,
            };

            this.Ajax.ajaxPostFn(url, data, (success) => {
                // console.log(success);
                this.displayDetailsPage(success, index);
            });
        }
 });
```

Now my requirement is that add next and previous button.

Comment: Java is to Javascript as pain is to painting. Please remove the java tag.

Comment: @NomadMaker okay i have removed it now.Have you any idea about this problem if yes,please help me.